# Twipsy not in Twitter bootstrap 2.0?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In the past, twitter bootstrap has got a Javascript plugin, "twipsy".
Now, in Bootstrap 2.0, the plugin doesn't appear.

Someone knows why? There's any way to obtain again that functionality?

Thanks! And sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has the [tooltips](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) plugin. That should do the same thing as Twipsy.